# Why can't I specify the exact number of images for a swapchain, but only minImageCount?

Tags: vulkan

Documentation for [VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0-wsi_extensions/html/vkspec.html#VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR) confuses me:

> minImageCount is the minimum number of presentable images that the
>   application needs. The implementation will either create the swapchain
>   with at least that many images, or it will fail to create the
>   swapchain.

This leads to some problems, namely I can't use fixed size arrays in the code since I don't know the exact number of images until runtime. Why this decision was made and is there any way to force the requested behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such approach allows hardware vendors/driver developers implement presentation engine in a more flexible way. Presentation is OS-dependent, each operating system has its own procedures responsible for displaying images on screen. There are OS-dependent extensions which allow for presentable surface creation, but Vulkan itself is a multi-platform API, and VkSwapchainKHR object is also common for all operating systems. Besides, number of swapchain images created by the drivers may depend not only on the OS, but also on other parameters specified during swapchain creation (like for example present mode). So such flexibility in managing the number of presentable images is necessary.

Comment: Can I at least know the biggest possible difference of requested image number and created? For example, can it be safe to create a statically sized array of `numImagesRequested + 1` elements (or `+2`, `+3` etc)? The specification only have an entry for `VkSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR::maxImageCount` which is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: I don't have enough knowledge to claim that `minImageCount + 2` will always be enough. It may be enough for the time being but future platforms may behave differently. But what is wrong with using dynamically sized arrays? Or with having a fixed-sized array with, lets say, 20 elements but with additional variable holding the actual number of images?

Comment: I'm using `std::vector`, no problem with that (thought I'd like to avoid dynamic allocations). Just want to bring more order to the code, a personal preference, if you wish.

Comment: I was just wandering if there are some platform constrains or if these are just personal preferences. I fully understand that. Unfortunately I'm afraid using `std::vector` is the most reasonable solution (a good compromise between easiness of use, code maintainability, using proven solutions/tested libraries etc.). Besides, these dynamic allocations don't happen too often (swapchain recreation is usually performed very rarely).

Comment: "not too often" -- more like once for a sane app. Some apps do not need to recreate swapchain. And for those that do, it is reasonable assumption the image count would be the same as before. Plus you can control when the initial allocation happens with `.reserve()`. For extra demanding people, the vector takes an allocator object which can be customized.

Comment: @Ekzuzy Just personal preferences. For my simple test, indeed vectors initialization happens only once. But in more complex scenario there can be case where this should happen every frame and where `std::array` would be handy (though I can't name right now such a scenario). And btw, the `Qt` framework uses that approach in their examples and have a constant [`QVulkanWindow::MAX_CONCURRENT_FRAME_COUNT`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qvulkanwindow.html#MAX_CONCURRENT_FRAME_COUNT-var), and it's interesting how they can guarantee this value.

Comment: @nikitablack I don't think they can guarantee this. But are You sure this constant refers to the number of swapchain images? Maybe it's used to define the number of separate sets of command buffers which are used to prepare a frame of animation? Something like number of prerendered/prerecorded frames.

Comment: @Ekzuzy You're right - I'm not sure. But from their examples it looks like it's related to concurrent frame count (i.e. N uniform buffers, N descriptor sets etc).

Comment: @nikitablack Read about rendering resources in [Intel's API without Secrets](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/api-without-secrets-introduction-to-vulkan-part-4) tutorial. I think it's the same concept.

Comment: @Ekzuzy I did. Your render resource hold (among other stuff) a framebuffer. Framebuffer contains an image from a swap chain. So if you have more resources than the number of images in a swap chain you'll end up with resources which reference the same swap chain image. I don't understand the benefit of this approach.

Comment: @nikitablack Not in the approach described in the tutorial. These resources are independent from the swapchain. And in the article, framebuffer is created on demand, just after swapchain image is acquired. This is done to simplify framebuffer management and maintenance. And this way number of frame resources is independent of the number of swapchain images, so You can adjust it to Your needs and don't rely on the specific number of images driver creates for a swapchain.

Comment: @Ekzuzy Ok, thank you very much. I need to reread the tutorial.